# How to have specific error message on SQL Insert Statement with Parameters using vb.net?

Tags: sql, vb.net

Basically, I have a SQL Insert Statement with some Paramaters:

```
sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO tbl_visitor_info(lname, fname) VALUES(?, ?)"
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection(access_connection)
    Try
        con.Open()
        With cmd
            .Connection = con
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .CommandText = sqlQuery

            .Parameters.Add("@lname", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = lname
            .Parameters.Add("@fname", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = fname
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    con.Close()
```

Now, for example, an Invalid Data was entered for either one of the Parameters
Is it possible for Prompt which parameter causes the error?
The Try Catch only returns "There is an Error in your INSERT Statement"
I am using MS Access 2010 as database.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the question marks in your query with the parameter names:

```
sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO tbl_visitor_info(lname, fname) VALUES(@lname, @fname)"
```